# What is the equivalent of Java's elementToBeClickable in Selenium using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am new to Ruby scripting for the Automation framework. I am experimenting Selenium and Ruby combination for automation framework. What I've discovered is that, there is no elementToBeClickable in Ruby selenium? I have a script where I click on the element, using the regular click method. However that click doesn't work, element doesn't get clicked. So I am thinking of waiting for the element to be clickable, however Selenium's ruby library doesn't have that method like the ones in Java and C#. How do you guys wait for the element to be clickable in Ruby?

```
  def click_more_actions_button
    more_actions_id = 'btnMoreActions'
    el = @wd.find_element(id: more_actions_id)
    el.click
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable (By.id("foo")));
```

Below lines is exact equivalent of above java code,

```
wait.until { driver.find_element(id: "foo").enabled? }
```

Fact is the elementToBeClickable method in java is misleading, actually it will check enabled state of element.

Refer the implementation of elementToBeClickable in ExpectedContions.java,

```
  /**
   * An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.
   *
   * @param locator used to find the element
   * @return the WebElement once it is located and clickable (visible and enabled)
   */
  public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> elementToBeClickable(final By locator) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
      @Override
      public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        WebElement element = visibilityOfElementLocated(locator).apply(driver);
        try {
          if (element != null && element.isEnabled()) {
            return element;
          }
          return null;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
          return null;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "element to be clickable: " + locator;
      }
    };
  }
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java) in github.

Comment: So, I created a "clicked?" method that waits until the element is enabled, however, I am still unable to click on the element. Any idea? Check the updated code.

Comment: Editing the question with the answer will mislead that I have duplcated your question.Please revert it.  Please raise it as seprate question with html dom and explaination about what your trying to do. It has to be analysed based on the html you are tring ot interact

Comment: Please raise it has seperate question with 3 items. Piece Html dom that you are trying to interact, The code which is failing and the expection it is throw.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no such direct method in Ruby programming language.

Here is the alternative to check and wait until an element is displayed and enabled to perform operations on it like click, send_keys, etc:

```rb
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
element = wait.until{
   tmp_element = driver.find_element(:name, 'password')
   tmp_element if tmp_element.enabled? && tmp_element.displayed?
}
```

Using `wait.until`, we can do it.
Hope it will help you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.